# How to check in an array list if an item is immediately followed by another - Java

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I am currently stuck on a part of my project.

I cannot figure out how to (in Java) to check whether in an existing array list, an item is followed immediately by another item. So, for example, if x is followed by y in the array list: a, b, c, x, y, z.

It needs to be a recurring thing as there can be multiple same values in the list, so multiple x and y items for example.

Can someone help me with coming up with the code for this? It needs to be a method that returns true or false.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to iterate through an ArrayList in java?

Comment: Show us what you did so far

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: check the index(es) for object a, and check whether or not index+1 is object b

Answer (score 3):

Just loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++)
```

-1... because the LAST element couldn't possibly match, as it is not followed by anything.

You can retrieve an item at an index as `list.get(i)`, and of course the element that follows it with `list.get(i + 1)`.

Surely you can put it together with this information (I'm loathe to give more; this feels like homework).

Comment: Thank you for this. I will try this now.

Answer (score -1):

> If (list.indexOf(item1) == list.indexOf(item2) -1)
>   { return true ;
>   }